# Combine multiple tables in MySQL for View

Tags: mysql, join, view

Below is my code I am using to try and create a view from 3 tables.  I am getting an error "Error Code 1052 fighterID is ambiguous".  This is the first view I've ever tried to create and I can't discern what I'm doing wrong in order to populate the view correctly.

```
CREATE VIEW championsList AS (
SELECT champions.fighterId, fighters.fighterId, weightClasses.weightClassId, fighters.firstName, fighters.LastName, weightClasses.weightClass
FROM champions, fighters
INNER JOIN fighters champions
ON
champions.fighterId = fighters.fighterId
INNER JOIN champions weightClasses
ON
champions.weightClassId=weightClasses.weightClass



fighters
1 Frank Smith 
2 Fred  Lewis

champions
1 2
2 1

weightClasses
1 heavyweight
2 bantemweight

ChampionsList
Frank Smith bantemweight
Fred Lewis Heavyweight
```

Answer (score 1):

Give an alias to the two columns which are both named `fighterId` in their respective tables:

```
CREATE VIEW championsList AS (
    SELECT champions.fighterId AS c_fighterId, fighters.fighterId AS f_fighterId,
        weightClasses.weightClassId, fighters.firstName, fighters.LastName,
        weightClasses.weightClass
    FROM champions INNER JOIN fighters
        ON champions.fighterId = fighters.fighterId
    INNER JOIN weightClasses
        ON champions.weightClassId = weightClasses.weightClass
)
```

I also cleaned up your query to what I believe you intended.

Comment: So this created the view - however the view is not populated with any data.  I'm trying to use the champions table - to relate to the fighters table to pull back the fighters name.  What am I not including?

Comment: Is it possible that your query is not returning anything or at least not returning what your expect?  Could you test the query by itself to check for this?

Comment: It's not returning anything.  Below is what I'm trying to accomplish - I just can't seem to put the puzzle pieces together to make it happen

Comment: I edited the question to show an example of what I want to do.

Comment: I'm afraid you might be confused about what a view does in MySQL.  A view is really nothing more than a temporary table, existing in the same namespace as your other tables.  So in your question, you can imagine taking the output from your query, and sticking it into a table called `championsList`.  Anything which the query does not output will not give you your desired output, at least not without doing more work (which is another question).

Comment: I understand that - Maybe my question is, how do I populate that table with a firstName instead of the fighterID.  For Example, if fighterId 1 is Frank Smith, and he's listed on the champions table with fighterId 1.  How do I populate champions list by converting the number "1" to "Frank Smith"

Comment: I can't answer this without also seeing your data.  My advice at this point would be for you to open a new question.  Make sure to show your data and table structure along with desired output.